# iOS UITableView cellule

Tags: ios, tableview

```
ApplicationViewController *a=[mesApplications objectAtIndex:3];
```

mesApplications it's an array that contain  ApplicationViewController object, and want my `UIViewConroller` cellule display some propertie that every ApplicationViewController contain, and when i use this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    // Configuration des cellules
    ApplicationViewController *cellValue = [mesApplications objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = cellValue.name;
    NSLog(@"%@",cellValue);
    return cell;
}
```

the Log it's empty, and i dont know the solution?

Comment: Where did you add objects to `mesApplications` and where did you allocated it ?

Comment: i declared in Master.h
NSMutableArray *mesApplications; and i impliment in .m mesApplications=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
and when i finesh peuling object i add in the liste [mesApplications addObject:application];

Comment: when i try 
ApplicationViewController *a=[mesApplications objectAtIndex:3];
NSLog(@"%@",a.name); it works , but inside tableView Methode does not work!!

Comment: Is the tableview methods is in Matser.m file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is a short implementation based on your description. It seems to behave correctly.
I hope you will find what is missing.

Regards

ViewController.nib consists of a single UITableView including an UIButton (calling addApplications)

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ApplicationViewController : UIViewController

@property   NSString*   name;

@end

@interface ViewController : UITableViewController

@property   ( nonatomic, retain )   NSArray*                mesApplications;

- ( IBAction ) addApplications: ( id ) sender;

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ApplicationViewController

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.mesApplications.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell*    cell            =   [ tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: @"MyTableViewCell" ];

    if ( !cell )
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"MyTableViewCell"];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }

    ApplicationViewController*  pApp    =   [ self.mesApplications objectAtIndex: indexPath.row ];
    [ cell.detailTextLabel setText: pApp.name ];
    NSLog(@"%@", pApp);
    return cell;
}

- ( IBAction ) addApplications: ( id ) sender
{
    ApplicationViewController*  pApp1   =   [ ApplicationViewController new ];
    pApp1.name  =   @"app1";

    ApplicationViewController*  pApp2   =   [ ApplicationViewController new ];
    pApp2.name  =   @"app2";

    ApplicationViewController*  pApp3   =   [ ApplicationViewController new ];
    pApp3.name  =   @"app3";

    self.mesApplications =  [ NSArray arrayWithObjects: pApp1, pApp2, pApp3, nil];

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

@end
```

And console dump

```
2013-03-11 13:38:17.132 kokio[10353:907] <ApplicationViewController: 0x1c535190>
2013-03-11 13:38:17.139 kokio[10353:907] <ApplicationViewController: 0x1c535260>
2013-03-11 13:38:17.142 kokio[10353:907] <ApplicationViewController: 0x1c535390>
```

Comment: it doesn't work , in my ApplicationViewconroller i have id(int), name(NSString), level(int)...

Comment: Edited my response, you might be missing [ self.tableView reloadData ]; after adding value